# Java android get byte[] from server

Tags: java, android

Hi I want to do something like this : I want to send a data to server and wait for receiver byte[] from server . the server will send the array when everything gets. But I want do some timeout becouse sometimes server don't get everything and nothing send.

I do this but it doesn't work. My application always wait for byte[]

```
 public class MyClientTask1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, byte[]> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";
        byte[] data;
        int count;

        MyClientTask1(String addr, int port) {
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
//            if (pingHost(1000)) {
            socket = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                String number = "10";

                String sendMessage = number + "\n";
                bw.write(sendMessage);
                bw.flush();
                InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
                data = new byte[100];
                count = stream.read(data);

                if(stream.read() == null)
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                count = stream.read(data);
               if( count != 0){
                    data = null;
                }

//                while ((count = stream.read(data)) != -1){
//                    count=stream.read(data);
//                }


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isSuccsess = false;
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("la", "nie udało sie");
                isSuccsess = false;
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
            super.onPostExecute(bytes);
            if(bytes != null) {
                if (bytes[0] == (byte) 0xF && bytes[1] == (byte) 0xA && bytes[2] == (byte) 0xA && bytes[3] == (byte) 0xD) {
                    showToast("zgadza się");
                } else {
                    showToast("nie zgadza się");
                }
            }
            else{
                showToast("nie ma nic");
            }
            pbWheel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Would setting a read timeout for the input stream of the `Socket` itself by calling [`setSoTimeout(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) on the socket instance help?

Comment: @clownba0t yes it help but I have question : after receiving data from the server receives a response in the form of 4 bytes. It will be work what I do ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what you're asking - perhaps try rephrasing?

Comment: @clownba0t server will be send not a byte[] but byte by byte